# CSS dropdown menu - mobile support

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have constructed this relatively simple drop-down menu using CSS. I am worried about whether all devices treat touch events the same - i.e. do all touch devices have a cursor that is moved after a touch? I don't have neither the time or resource to test this, so my best bet is asking here.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/e1zkksgv/) is an example, I would like to ask if this method of activating the drop-down will work on *most* mobile devices?

#### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="userpanel dropdown last-vertical">   <span>User Name</span>

        <ul class="userpanel dropdown-body">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/users/view">
                            <i class="fa fa-lg fa-user"></i> Profile
                        </a>

            </li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/users/settings">
                            <i class="fa fa-lg fa-cog"></i> Settings
                        </a>

            </li>
            <li>
                <form action="/users/logout" method="POST">
                    <button type="submit" class="dropdown-item">    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-sign-out"></i> Log out</button>
                </form>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

#### CSS

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.userpanel.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 1.5rem;
    z-index: 10;
    border: solid transparent;
    border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px;
    cursor: default;
}
.userpanel.dropdown span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.userpanel.dropdown .dropdown-item {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    color: black;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.userpanel.dropdown .dropdown-item:hover {
    background-color: lightgray;
}
.userpanel.dropdown-body li {
    margin:0;
}
.userpanel.dropdown:hover {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border-color: lightgray;
    color: black;
}
.userpanel.dropdown:hover .dropdown-body {
    display: block;
}
.userpanel.dropdown-body {
    position: absolute;
    top: 4rem;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    border: solid lightgray;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px 1px;
    background: #f1f1f1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the W3 documentation (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes) it might be buggy. Your method strongly relies on the `:hover` pseudo-class in order to activate the dropdown. The `:hover` pseudo-class (or event), relies on having a peripheral device (like a mouse or a trackpad), which is capable of distinguishing between the events of pointing at something (aka hovering) and clicking on something.

In mobile development, you will see that major UI frameworks substitute the `:hover` event for the `click` event when it comes to displaying drop-downs (see Bootstrap navigation bar). On a touchscreen device, it is relatively easy to click instead of hover on something, regardless of how experienced the user of the mobile handset might be.